# Grails and Bonsai Elasticsearch

Tags: grails, heroku, elasticsearch, bonsai-elasticsearch

I've been trying to use Bonsai Elasticsearch with my Grails application, but I can't get it to work using the Elasticsearch plugin. What I understood from the configuration manual, it should be just:

```
elasticSearch.client.mode = 'transport'
elasticSearch.client.hosts = [
    [host:'https://ixaav0lo:n98bya6pyh9rdaiu@ginkgo-1003161.us-east-1.bonsai.io', port:443]
]
```

Yet it's not working for me. Also, it doesn't HAVE to be with Bonsai, it could be with SearchBox Elasticsearch also, whatever works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any exception / error ?

Answer (score 1):

The ES plugin doesn't support HTTP; only the transport protocol is supported. Check with bonsai.io whether they allow the transport protocol. If they do, your config should be

```
elasticSearch.client.mode = 'transport'
elasticSearch.client.hosts = [
    [host:'ixaav0lo:n98bya6pyh9rdaiu@ginkgo-1003161.us-east-1.bonsai.io', port:9300]
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it did't work though. Sadly, I think Bonsai only works with HTTP. I'll see if I can find another workaround with some Java plugin

Comment: Depending on your situation it might be less effort to use the plugin and run your own ES cluster. Just something to consider.

Comment: Problem is, I was planning on hosting on Heroku or Cloud Foundry. Can I make my own clusters there without using these 3rd party providers? Or should I just go with a VPS hosting?